# NodeJs Express: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: node.js, express

Node express crashes when the response is in a setInterval. I want to test some things in the frontend when the response is delayed a bit. For this I have passed the response as a callback to the setInterval function in my nodeJs Express:

```js
router.post('/survey', userMiddleware.isLoggedIn, (req, res ,next) => {
  setInterval(() => {
     res.status(200).send({
      message: 'Upload success!'
    });
  }, 3000);
});
```

However, I then receive an error:

```
node:_http_outgoing:576
    throw new ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT('set');
    ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:576:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/node/node-express-jwt-test/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:794:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/node/node-express-jwt-test/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:174:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (/node/node-express-jwt-test/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:278:15)
    at ServerResponse.send (/node/node-express-jwt-test/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:162:21)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/node/node-express-jwt-test/routes/router.js:83:22)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}

Node.js v17.5.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You keep sending the response at an interval of 3000ms _ the delay is done but the it’s repeated

Use the ‘setTimeout(function, 3000)’ to send once

Read more about set timeout here https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setTimeout.asp

So your code Should be like this:

```
 router.post('/survey', userMiddleware.isLoggedIn, (req, res ,next) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
          res.status(200).send({
           message: 'Upload success!'
     });
   }, 3000 );
 });
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't quite understand your answer. How do you know about 300ms? And why is the answer repeated?

Comment: That was a typo I edited my answers

Comment: ok. But how ever. I have question again. The setTimout funtion response after 3s. Why did you mean that sending the response repeated?

Comment: Ohhh I get now  set interval is like a iteration statements it’s keeps running after the first delay so every 3 seconds the function is being ran and after express response sent the first response it’s breaks the tcp connect so you can’t send anything back to that client again if you need to send something repeatedly you need to implement web socket to handle the stream connection __. Hope this answer your question

Comment: Oh no. Now I see that I took setInterval and that's why the error occurred. You are right, of course. I have to use setTimeout! My fault